# Рекурсия в цикле

Tags: php

```
function printItem($item, &$items, $childrens, $active) {
    if(count($items) == 0) return;
    echo '<div><a'.(in_array($item->id, $active)?'class="active "':'')
        .($item->external?'rel="external "':'')
        .'href="'.$item->link.'">'.$item->title.'</a>';
    while(true) {
        $key = array_search($item->id, $childrens);
        if(!$key) break;
        unset($childrens[$key]);
        printItem($items[$key], $items, $childrens, $active)
    }
    echo '</div>';
    unset($items[$item->id]);
}
?>

<div id="menu">
    <div class="menu">
        <?php foreach($items as $item) printItem($item, $items, $childrens, $active) ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

На items приходит массив такого вида:

```
Array (
[1] => MenuDB Object
    (
        [format_date:AbstractObjectDB:private] => %d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S
        [id:AbstractObjectDB:private] => 1
        [properties:AbstractObjectDB:private] => Array
            (
                [type] => Array
                    (
                        [value] => 1
                        [validator] => ValidateID
                        [type] => 
                    )

                [title] => Array
                    (
                        [value] => Меню1
                        [validator] => ValidateTitle
                        [type] => 
                    )

                [link] => Array
                    (
                        [value] => #
                        [validator] => ValidateURL
                        [type] => 
                    )

                [parent_id] => Array
                    (
                        [value] => 
                        [validator] => ValidateID
                        [type] => 
                    )

                [external] => Array
                    (
                        [value] => 0
                        [validator] => ValidateBoolean
                        [type] => 
                    )

            )

        [table_name:protected] => menu
    )
...
```

Проблема заключается в следующем, если идет рекурсия то items как ссылочная переменная должна перезаписываться, однако при второй иторации цикла элемент берется 2, хотя после рекурсии должен быть 14, т.к. 2 должен быть удален. Если вызывать items внутри цикла перед вызовом функции, то можно увидеть, что items при второй иторации начинается с 14 позиции, т.е. функция отработала правильно, однако при второй иторации в функцию приходит 2 элемент с items, хотя он должен быть удален из-за это происходит каша. Как решить данную проблему? Спасибо.

Comment: Не касательно вопроса. Настораживает, что у вас при таком подходе получится дикая вложенность div'ов, поскольку они сначала открываются друг в друге, а в конце все по очереди закрываются

Comment: Так же крайне стремное решение делать unset итерируемому массиву. Вообще у вас дичайше переусложненное решение. Лучше опишите, что вы хотите получить в итоге, скорее всего решить можно гораздо проще.

Comment: @rjhdby Мне нужно собрать меню. В items приходит объект, с помощью которого я собираю его. Спасибо однако я уже нашел решение. Перед осноным циклом пишу следующие строчки: 
    `<?php $reshit = array(); ?>
      <?php foreach($items as $k=>$v) { ?>
       <?php
           if($v->parent_id == 0 && !isset($reshit[$k])) $reshit[$k] = $v;
       ?>
    <?php } ?>`

Comment: @rjhdby Получается я уже предварительно отсевую лишнее. Все равно спасибо, что отозвались.